# Switch statement in one action or multiple actions in Rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Im making this site for clothes where I have different categories and I have a resource named "Items" for managing every clothing (since I've read somewhere, one controller per resource).

So for example, if I want to display jackets, I have a route like this:

```
get '/jackets', to: 'items#index', page: 'jackets'
```

And the controller has an index action that has a switch statement with all the different possibilities inside (I'm using scopes here):

```
def index
    case params[:page]

    # Women / Clothing
    when "clothing"
      @items = Item.clothing
    when "beachwear"
      @items = Item.beachwear
    when "coats"
      @items = Item.coats
```

Is this the right way do do it? Or should I make a single action for each kind of category that I have?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english

Edit: I have something close to 100 categories.

Comment: aren't these categories saved in some table ?

Comment: Not really, should I? Do you have some insight on how to model this?
What I have is the Item model with a column called "category". Thanks.

Comment: I think it would be easier to do something like `Category.find(name: params[:category]).items` ( of course handle wrong category names ) but this way you won't need to do a 100 case/when

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are `Item.clothing`, `Item.coats`, etc, scopes or? How have you implemented your model?

Why not just do something like:

```
def index
  @items = Item.where(category: params[:category])
end
```

(provided, of course, that you add a `category` field in your `Item` model)

*note that I changed `params[:page]` to `params[:category]` for semantic reasons*

Comment: Yes, those are scopes.
This looks way better than what I actually have. Thank you.